# Sqlite query crashing on alpha lookup

Tags: android, sqlite

I’m having a problem with a simple SQLite database with a String Part number and String Description whereby if I try to create a query to lookup a passed in part number when I pass in an entirely numeric part number it works but if the passed in part number contains an alpha character it crashes.

Here are the pertinent code snippets;

```
public static final String TABLE_PARTS_HISTORY = "tbl_parts_history";
public static final String COLUMN_PART_NO = "partNoValue";
public static final String COLUMN_DESC = "descValue";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mbHistory.db";
…
// Parts Database creation sql statement
private static final String PARTS_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_PARTS_HISTORY + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_PART_NO
        + " text not null, " + COLUMN_DESC + " text not null);";
…
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    // Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Starting onCreate " + DATABASE_CREATE);
    database.execSQL(PARTS_TABLE_CREATE);
}
…
public boolean partNoAlreadyExists(String partNoValue) {
    // Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Starting getQuery");
    open();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_PARTS_HISTORY,
            partNoSelectColumn, SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PART_NO + " = "
                    + partNoValue, null, null, null, null);
    boolean exists = cursor.getCount() > 0;
    cursor.close();
    close();
    return exists;
}// End of partNoAlreadyExists
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what happens when you pass a number with alpha character?

Comment: When entering a part no with an alpha character I get the screen pop up "Unfortunately (program name) has stopped". <br>Debugging it I got to the part in the code where it attempts to build a cursor to see if the part no already exists in the database ( Cursor cursor = database.query(...). Stepping further through the debug it goes to the Android View.java try/catch where it throws the ambiguous "IllegalStateException("Could not execute method of the activity" message.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have found an answer by replacing the cursor method I’ve listed which utilized the SQLite query method with the SQLite rawQuery method and inserting single quotes around the passed in partNo when building the rawQuery selection string.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
    + SQLiteHelper.TABLE_PARTS_HISTORY
    + " WHERE " + SQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PART_NO + " = '" + partNo + "'", null);
```

Originally when passing a numeric partNo it automatically cast the number into the selection string. But when passing an alpha partNo (without the single quotes wrapping it), it would attempt to treat the partNo as an alpha method call and fail. I was confused because when it crashed, and the logged try/catch failure message reported it couldn’t execute the method, I thought it was referring to my method (not to the “method” it had extracted for partNo.

Many thanks to rawcode and M D for pointing me in the right direction.